# How to change the standard CRUD action mapping?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have posts and comments, which have one-to-one relationship, mapped like this

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
```

[This standard mapping](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) makes them depend on columns :id which are their primary keys, I want it to be the same except they would depend on another table column :num (since I cannot change primary key so freely and it's auto-incremented anyway), how can I change the mapping to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can just have your `comments` controller find by using a different method. For example:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @post = Posts.find_by_num(params[:post_id])
    @comments = @post.comments
  end
end
```

Comment: yeah, at the end i did something like that. it's not really pretty (i have my restful routes to show posts but routes to posts' and comments' images, to deleting those posts and comments still use id) but it seems rails don't like when you want something which wasn't intended by its creators -_-